# Sort by a list by name and age descending

Tags: sorting, java-8

I am trying to sort a list by lastName and age descending using Java 8 - I can get to the point of sorting both firstName and age - but not by firstName and age descending. Please help.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
class ABCE {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
}

// Sort by firstName and then by age descending
list = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(ABCE::getFirstName).thenComparing(ABCE::getAge))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Oh got-it . To use thenComparingInt(ABCE::getAge).reversed()

Answer (score 0):

Did you want both name and age descending?  Your `reversed()` reverses all the comparisons prior.  If you just want to reverse based on ages, do it as follows. I simplified it somewhat by using a record with just a first name.

```
record ABCE(String getFirstName, int getAge) {
}
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    List<ABCE> list = List.of(new ABCE("A", 10),
            new ABCE("B", 10), new ABCE("B", 12),
            new ABCE("C", 10), new ABCE("C", 10));
    
    // Sort by firstName ascending and then by age descending
    list = list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ABCE::getFirstName)
                    .thenComparing(ABCE::getAge,
                            Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Prints

```
ABCE[getFirstName=A, getAge=10]
ABCE[getFirstName=B, getAge=12]
ABCE[getFirstName=B, getAge=10]
ABCE[getFirstName=C, getAge=10]
ABCE[getFirstName=C, getAge=10]
```